# "own" is redundant in the following text? I'm always confused about using this word

Tags: grammar, redundancy

In the following text, I feel that "own" makes my opinion clearer. I want to say that people have different priorities and therefore they need to weigh everything up themselves. so we could not give the same advice to all people. I tried to support my opinion by giving examples. In the end, I tried to emphasize that people should choose the best option based on their own needs. I think If I use "own" it would be clearer, but on the other hand I do not want to put redundant words.

> Some people believe that living in the city centre, near amenities, is
> more comfortable, but the housing in the city centre is expensive.
> Conversely, a similarly priced house in the suburbs is twice larger in
> size, which I think plays a pivotal role in the comfort of life.
> Therefore, which option should a person choose is dependent on their
> **own** priorities.

Could you please tell me whether I have used it properly or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the way you have it right now, and I would keep the "own" in that sentence. It does not feel redundant to me at all, plus it clarifies that people are choosing their *own* priorities, and not the priorities of *some other group*. Keep in mind that you could delete that "own" and it would still make sense, but I prefer it left in the sentence.